# Prove that the set of functions are functionally independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jacobian

Consider the set of $2n-1$ functions of $2n$ variables
\begin{gather*}
x_1y_1, x_2 y_2, \ldots, x_n y_n,\\
x_2 y_1^2,x_3 y_1^3, \ldots,x_n y_1^n. 
\end{gather*}
I need prove that these functions are functionally  independent. 
A long way is to find the rank of the jacobian
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
y_{{1}}&0&0&0&\ldots&x_{{1}}&0&0&0\\ 
0&y_{{2}}&0&0&\ldots&0&x_{{2}}&0&0\\
0&0&y_{{3}}&0&\ldots&0&0&x_{{3}}&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&y_{{n}}&\ldots&0&0&\ldots&x_{{n}}\\
 0&{y_{{1}}}^{2}&0&0&\ldots&2x_{{2}}{y_{{1}}}&0&\ldots&0\\ 
0&0&{y_{{1}}}^{3}&0&\ldots&3x_{{3}}{y_{{1}}}^{2}&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots &\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&{y_{{1}}}^{n}&\ldots&nx_{{n}}{y_{{1}}}^{n-1}&0&\ldots&0
\end{vmatrix}
$$

but on this way I have got big and bad determinants.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What does "functionally indepeneded" mean?

Comment: If you want to prove that $k$ monomials $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_k$ are algebraically independent, it suffices to show that all the monomials $m_1^{a_1} m_2^{a_2} \cdots m_k^{a_k}$ (with $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ being nonnegative integers) are distinct (i.e., if two $k$-tuples $\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right)$ and $\left(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k\right)$ satisfy $m_1^{a_1} m_2^{a_2} \cdots m_k^{a_k} = m_1^{b_1} m_2^{b_2} \cdots m_k^{b_k}$, then $\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\right) = \left(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k\right)$). This should be an easy nonogram-like exercise in your situation.

Comment: "functionally independet" means that their jacobian has maximal rank. But of course an algebraically independence  is enought

Answer (score 0):

Here is some divide-and-conquer approach. First, the functions $x_2y_2, \dots , x_ny_n$ are the  only terms that contain $y_i$, $i\ge 2$. Hence this set of functions is linearly independent and not contained in the linear hull of all the other functions.

So it remains to consider the functions $x_1y_1 \dots x_n y_1^n$. But all these are linearly independent because exactly one term depends on $x_i$, $i=1\dots n$.

Hence, the functions in question are linearly independent.

Comment: I asked about  functionaly indepenedet but not about  linearly independent